# Rhomobile: Read txt file and show content Ruby

Tags: ruby, rhomobile, rhodes

i want to open, read and show a txt file in my Rhomobile app.
First, i want to show the complete content of the file. But here is my problem.

```
def text
fileName = File.join(Rho::RhoApplication::get_base_app_path(), '/app/test.txt')
    f = File.open(fileName, 'r')
    while line = f.gets
    puts line
    end
  f.close
    redirect :action => :index  
    end
```

the code read the txt file, but how can i call the method and show the results on a page.
I don´t know whats the varaible is?

Please help me :) Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you only want to read the whole file, you can use this method:

```
@file_content = File.read(fileName);
```

You can assign the file's content to a instance variable (prefixed with an @) and show it in your view (`*.html.erb` or `*.erb`):

```
File content: <%= @file_content %>
```

Additionally, if you call `redirect` then your view won't be rendered and the user will be redirected to the specified action  (`index`). So the code for the controller action should be this:

```
def text
  @file_content = File.read(fileName);
  render action: 'text'
end
```